# Screen record in android without mediaprojection

Tags: android

I tried to make a screen recorder application in android.
(like [AZ Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.hecorat.screenrecorder.free&hl=en&gl=US))

As far as I know, mediaprojection must be needed to screen capture.

Are there any other ways to capture the screen without mediaprojection?

Target Android API level is 30.

Answer (score 0):

There used to be an ADB command (more about that here)

https://www.howtogeek.com/176956/how-to-record-your-android-devices-screen-with-android-4.4-kitkat/

Other than that I'm not aware of any other way other than using media projection or root permissions.